# Auto reload with play2

Tags: java, maven, playframework, maven-plugin

This is my play2 project having maven nature:

**pom.xml with relevant code:**

```
<packaging>play2</packaging>
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.code.play2-maven-plugin</groupId>
    <artifactId>play2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${play2.plugin.version}</version>

    <extensions>true</extensions>
    <configuration>
      <!-- only if using database evolutions -->
      <serverJvmArgs>-DapplyEvolutions.default=true</serverJvmArgs>
    </configuration>

    <executions>
      <!-- only if there are assets in the project -->
      <execution>
        <id>default-play2-compile-assets</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>closure-compile</goal>
          <goal>coffee-compile</goal>
          <goal>less-compile</goal>
        </goals>    
      </execution>                    
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

I run the project with command:

```
mvn play2:run
```

But each time I do any change to the file, I have to do `mvn compile play2:run` and then reload the page.

Isn't any feature to reload with current changes without doing any maven compile each time ?

**NOTE:**

I found that using `mvn play2:run`, it always runs in `PROD` mode. So this seems to be the problem. Don't know how to run it in `DEV` mode.

**Console:**

```
[play] [info] play - Application started (Prod)
[play] [info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0%0:9000
```

Comment: Is there any reason why your project have `mvn nature`? Isnt `sbt` enough?

Comment: No, my project is a submodule of a parent project and all are of maven nature with their own pom.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I found is to use `activator` instead:

```
activator run
```

And to run at specific port say `9543` use:

```
activator run -Dhttp.port=9543
```

Answer (score 0):

Running in DEV mode and auto-reloading features are not implemented yet.

I've started to work on these features recently, but it's not easy and I cannot predict wren it will be available. Sorry.